# Cannot create a TTL index on a field that already has an index. ...really?

Tags: mongodb

From the [10Gen Docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/):

> "You cannot create a TTL index on a field that already has an index."

However, it seems like this works just fine. **What do the docs really mean?**

---

In this example I create multiple indexes on field `d` before adding TTL. TTL appears correct:

```
"expireAfterSeconds" : 5
```

and the documents are removed correctly.

mongo shell:

```
> db.boo.ensureIndex({a: 1, b: 1, d: -1})
{
    "createdCollectionAutomatically" : true,
    "numIndexesBefore" : 1,
    "numIndexesAfter" : 2,
    "ok" : 1
}
> db.boo.ensureIndex({d: -1})
{
    "createdCollectionAutomatically" : false,
    "numIndexesBefore" : 2,
    "numIndexesAfter" : 3,
    "ok" : 1
}
> db.boo.ensureIndex({d: 1}, {expireAfterSeconds: 5});
{
    "createdCollectionAutomatically" : false,
    "numIndexesBefore" : 3,
    "numIndexesAfter" : 4,
    "ok" : 1
}
> db.boo.getIndexes()
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "test.boo"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "a" : 1,
            "b" : 1,
            "d" : -1
        },
        "name" : "a_1_b_1_d_-1",
        "ns" : "test.boo"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "d" : -1
        },
        "name" : "d_-1",
        "ns" : "test.boo"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "d" : 1
        },
        "name" : "d_1",
        "ns" : "test.boo",
        "expireAfterSeconds" : 5
    }
]
```

### Edit/Summary:

The combination that is actually restricted is adding a TTL expiration to an existing **index**, like this:

```
> db.boo.ensureIndex({d: 1});
{
    "createdCollectionAutomatically" : true,
    "numIndexesBefore" : 1,
    "numIndexesAfter" : 2,
    "ok" : 1
}
> db.boo.ensureIndex({d: 1}, {expireAfterSeconds: 5});
{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "Index with name: d_1 already exists with different options",
    "code" : 85
}
```

Comment: Obviously, documentation and reality do not match in this case. You might want to [report this as a bug](https://jira.mongodb.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa) or documentation error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have actually created different index type (descending).

Commands:

```
db.boo.ensureIndex({d: -1})
```

and

```
db.boo.ensureIndex({d: 1})
```

will create two separate indexes (although on the same field).

If you try to create a descending TTL index:

```
db.boo.ensureIndex({d: -1}, {expireAfterSeconds: 5})
```

you will get an error:

> Index with name ... already exists with different options

If you try to be "clever" and change the name of the index you will get:

> Index with pattern... already exists with different options

I guess you should submit a bug to describe that more precisely in their documentation / tutorial.

Comment: How do I get rid of the old index, if I decide that I just want to change the options being used?

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare use the `dropIndex` method to remove the old index.